# Display UILabel from a method of a class

Tags: objective-c, ios, class

I have a custom class called "Fraction" and its method "display" in which i'd like to show on View a UILabel:

```
-(void)display{
    UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 200, 40)];
    [myLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [myLabel setText:@"______"];
    [self.view addSubview:myLabel];
 }
```

but I get this error on the last line:

> Proprety 'view' not found on object of type 'Fraction *'

How can I solve?

(iPhone "single view" application, Xcode 4.5.2)

Comment: Does "Fraction" inherit from UIView? UIViewController? NSObject?

Comment: Fraction inherit from NSObject

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to add a subview to something that isn't a UIView - in your 'display' method's context, 'self' refers to an object of type Fraction. If Fraction doesn't have a UIView property called view and doesn't inherit from one that does (such as UIViewController), there is no reason for it to recognise what you're trying to do there. The correct way to do this would be to have an instance method in "Fraction" that returns an NSString with the fraction's representation. Use this returned value to do anything that the view requires, such as adding it to a UILabel's text property.

It's important to understand correct MVC - in your example, you're completely abusing the MVC abstraction and having a data object affect the view. (M and V should not be interacting directly).

Comment: ok I see, is there any way to do so? Can't I refer to UIView in the method itself? I know I have to edit this part: self.view

Comment: Like I said, define your UILabel either in a xib/storyboard or programatically in a UIViewController. Add a method that returns an NSString representation of a fraction to the Fraction class and assign this NSString to your UILabel's text property.

Answer (score 0):

In view controller.h

Fraction* fraction;

In view controller.m add this

```
UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 200, 40)];
    [myLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [myLabel setText:[fraction methodForLabelString]];
    [self.view addSubview:myLabel];
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

Check whether ‘self’ is a ViewController. addSubView is a method in UIView.